# How to do group concatenation in MySql only if a specific value/values are present in that group concat column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a list of employee and one employee can work in many departments.
I want a list of all employees and all departments that they work for only when they work at deptID 3 and 4.

I,e only if an employee works for dept 3 or 4, I want list of all the departments that he works for.

SQL query goes something like this to get employees and their working department:

```
SELECT  e.`Emp_ID`,e.`FirstName`,e.`Address`
,GROUP_CONCAT(edd.Dept_id) AS dept_ids
,GROUP_CONCAT(edd.`Dept_Name`) AS dept_names

FROM employee e
INNER JOIN emp_dept_details edd 
ON e.`Emp_ID` = edd.`Emp_ID`
GROUP BY e.`Emp_ID`;
```

Result:

```
"Emp_ID" "FirstName" "Address"  "dept_ids"       "dept_names"
"1"      "emp1"      "abcd"   "3,9,12,13,11" "Eng,ESC,Mech,EEE,MIS"
"2"      "emp2"      "abcd1"     "9,11,13,8"      "Eng,MIS,EEE,CIS"
```

So I don't want second record as deptID 3 or 4 is not there in the group_concat result.

Where as first record contains 3 so I want entire list "3,9,12,13,11"
Can I do it without nesting the query.
I've to deal with huge records so nesting will slow things down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already bringing the information you need together.  You just need a `having` clause:

```
SELECT e.`Emp_ID`, e.`FirstName`, e.`Address`,
      GROUP_CONCAT(edd.Dept_id) AS dept_ids,
      GROUP_CONCAT(edd.`Dept_Name`) AS dept_names
FROM employee e JOIN
     emp_dept_details edd 
     ON e.`Emp_ID` = edd.`Emp_ID`
GROUP BY e.`Emp_ID`
HAVING SUM( edd.Dept_id IN (3, 4) ) > 0;
```

The `HAVING` clause counts the number of times an employee is in the two departments.  The `> 0` says that the employee is in at least one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `exists` with a subquery

```
SELECT  e.`Emp_ID`,e.`FirstName`,e.`Address`
,GROUP_CONCAT(edd.Dept_id) AS dept_ids
,GROUP_CONCAT(edd.`Dept_Name`) AS dept_names    
  FROM employee e
 INNER JOIN emp_dept_details edd 
    ON e.`Emp_ID` = edd.`Emp_ID`
 WHERE exists ( SELECT 1 
                  FROM emp_dept_details d
                 WHERE d.`Dept_id` in (3,4) 
                   AND d.`Emp_ID` = e.`Emp_ID` ) 
 GROUP BY e.`Emp_ID`,e.`FirstName`,e.`Address`;
```

Comment: Can we do it without writing nested queries. Nesting will slow the query as I've to deal with high number of records.

Comment: @shreeshkatti queries with exists are mostly very speedy. Other than using subqueries, more join conditions might be added, but I don't think that case would be more performant.